# Regular expression forums in python with examples

Tags: python, regex, forums

I'm new to python and I'm working with code the requires me to make use of regular expressions substantially.

I've gone through the python documentation for regular expressions (http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

However, since I'm new to python I find it hard to actually implement the functions that are specified within the documentation with the data I need to work with.

I was wondering if there's a forum out there that explains regular expressions in python with multiple examples for each function and all its possible variations. The more the merrier.

I've found this (http://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html) and this (http://flockhart.virtualave.net/RBIF0100/regexp.html) so far. I've found them useful but I was wondering if there is something out there that's better.

Comment: If you've read the `re` section, I would suggest opening the interpreter or a blank script and just start playing around with them and learning from any mistakes.

Comment: I've been doing that, however I am on a deadline and I need all the help I can get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this [pythonregex](http://www.pythonregex.com/) , its python specific and generates python code for your regular expressions.

enjoy!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [RegexOne](http://www.regexone.com) for excellent tutorials on regular expressions in general.

You can use [Debuggex](http://www.debuggex.com) (which is built by me) if you want to visualize and understand what a specific regex is doing.

If you want something python-specific, you can try [Google's python regex tutorial](https://developers.google.com/edu/python/regular-expressions).

Comment: Wow that seems like excellent material @Sergiu. Will take my time and go through it. Thanks a lot! =D

Comment: I would love a forum specifically designed to work with python though, would you know any such forum?

Comment: thanks :) I've have looked at that before. Perhaps I should mention that I'd like something that works with more complex examples. Thanks a lot though, you have been very helpful :)